# Suppose $f:[0,\infty]\rightarrow$ to R and has continuous $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ f(x) → 0 as x → ∞. Show that f′(x)→0 as x→∞

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)$ $\rightarrow$ R and has continuous $f'(x)$ and $f''(x) $ .

$f(x) $$\rightarrow $0 as $x$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$. Given $f'(x)\rightarrow b$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

show that $b=0$

Get stuck in the first place, but I tried to use Mean Value Theorem and then connected it to the limits.

Any hint?

Comment: I hope you mean: **given** $f'(x) \to b$ as $x \to \infty$, show that $b=0$.

Comment: Sorry. Robert is right. Given $f'(x) \rightarrow b$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$ show that $b=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: consider

$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} $$

**Further hint**: use L'Hospital's rule.

**Notice** that to do that, you need the limit of $ f'(x) $ to exist. The counterexample has been mentioned

Comment: Sorry. After I get $$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0 $$ I still can't go on....

Comment: I'm not sure if L'Hospital's Rule can be used here. I believe what you mean is that $$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} =\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{1} $$ But isn't L'Hospital's Rule only available when $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} =\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{x}=\infty $$ or $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} =\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{x}=1$$

Comment: But, if I suppose that I already know f'(x)=0, I can have $$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} =\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)} $$ by L'Hospital Rule, as $$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} {f(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} {f'(x)} =0$$